# Cannot build TensorFlow on Windows

Tags: tensorflow

I downloaded and installed all of the prerequisites mentioned on the [TensorFlow Build from source on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) page, ran `python configure.py`, accepted all of the defaults, and ran `bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`, as that page directed.  Here is the result.

```
(venv) C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\tensorflow>python configure.py
You have bazel 5.0.0 installed.
Please specify the location of python. [Default is C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\tensorflow\venv\Scripts\python.exe]:

Found possible Python library paths:
  C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\tensorflow\venv\lib\site-packages]

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with ROCm support? [y/N]:
No ROCm support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]:
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is /arch:AVX]:

Would you like to override eigen strong inline for some C++ compilation to reduce the compilation time? [Y/n]:
Eigen strong inline overridden.

Would you like to interactively configure ./WORKSPACE for Android builds? [y/N]:
Not configuring the WORKSPACE for Android builds.

Preconfigured Bazel build configs. You can use any of the below by adding "--config=<>" to your build command. See .bazelrc for more details.
        --config=mkl            # Build with MKL support.
        --config=mkl_aarch64    # Build with oneDNN and Compute Library for the Arm Architecture (ACL).
        --config=monolithic     # Config for mostly static monolithic build.
        --config=numa           # Build with NUMA support.
        --config=dynamic_kernels        # (Experimental) Build kernels into separate shared objects.
        --config=v1             # Build with TensorFlow 1 API instead of TF 2 API.
Preconfigured Bazel build configs to DISABLE default on features:
        --config=nogcp          # Disable GCP support.
        --config=nonccl         # Disable NVIDIA NCCL support.

(venv) C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\tensorflow>bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=120
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from c:\users\me\documents\github\tensorflow\.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --experimental_repo_remote_exec
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  'build' options: --python_path=C:/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/tensorflow/venv/Scripts/python.exe
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from c:\users\me\documents\github\tensorflow\.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --define framework_shared_object=true --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --define=allow_oversize_protos=true --spawn_strategy=standalone -c opt --announce_rc --define=grpc_no_ares=true --noincompatible_remove_legacy_whole_archive --enable_platform_specific_config --define=with_xla_support=true --config=short_logs --config=v2 --define=no_aws_support=true --define=no_hdfs_support=true --experimental_cc_shared_library --experimental_link_static_libraries_once=false
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from c:\users\me\documents\github\tensorflow\.tf_configure.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/tensorflow/venv/Scripts/python.exe --action_env PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/tensorflow/venv/lib/site-packages --python_path=C:/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/tensorflow/venv/Scripts/python.exe --copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --host_copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --define=override_eigen_strong_inline=true
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from c:\users\me\documents\github\tensorflow\.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --deleted_packages=tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/benchmarks,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/jit/python_binding,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/jit/transforms,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/python_tests,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/ir,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/analysis,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/jit,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/lhlo_to_tfrt,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/lhlo_to_jitrt,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/tf_to_corert,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/tf_to_tfrt_data,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/saved_model,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/transforms/lhlo_gpu_to_tfrt_gpu,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/conversion,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/kernel,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/opdefs,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/runtime,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/util,tensorflow/core/tfrt/common,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/backends/cpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/backends/gpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/core_runtime,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/cpp_tests/core_runtime,tensorflow/core/tfrt/gpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/run_handler_thread_pool,tensorflow/core/tfrt/runtime,tensorflow/core/tfrt/saved_model,tensorflow/core/tfrt/graph_executor,tensorflow/core/tfrt/saved_model/tests,tensorflow/core/tfrt/tpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/utils
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:short_logs in file c:\users\me\documents\github\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --output_filter=DONT_MATCH_ANYTHING
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:v2 in file c:\users\me\documents\github\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --define=tf_api_version=2 --action_env=TF2_BEHAVIOR=1
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:windows in file c:\users\me\documents\github\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --copt=/W0 --host_copt=/W0 --copt=/Zc:__cplusplus --host_copt=/Zc:__cplusplus --copt=/D_USE_MATH_DEFINES --host_copt=/D_USE_MATH_DEFINES --features=compiler_param_file --copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --host_copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --cxxopt=/std:c++17 --host_cxxopt=/std:c++17 --config=monolithic --copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --host_copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --copt=-DNOGDI --host_copt=-DNOGDI --copt=/experimental:preprocessor --host_copt=/experimental:preprocessor --linkopt=/DEBUG --host_linkopt=/DEBUG --linkopt=/OPT:REF --host_linkopt=/OPT:REF --linkopt=/OPT:ICF --host_linkopt=/OPT:ICF --verbose_failures --features=compiler_param_file --distinct_host_configuration=false
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:monolithic in file c:\users\me\documents\github\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --define framework_shared_object=false --experimental_link_static_libraries_once=false
WARNING: Download from https://storage.googleapis.com/mirror.tensorflow.org/github.com/tensorflow/runtime/archive/e1212041914020e9ff402c8c3c04e5e3c771d166.tar.gz failed: class java.io.FileNotFoundException GET returned 404 Not Found
WARNING: Download from https://storage.googleapis.com/mirror.tensorflow.org/github.com/llvm/llvm-project/archive/5ae0472694f5d53c0b889a48dc042961291d2341.tar.gz failed: class java.io.FileNotFoundException GET returned 404 Not Found
INFO: Build options --copt, --cxxopt, --features, and 2 more have changed, discarding analysis cache.
ERROR: C:/users/me/documents/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:1034:21: //tensorflow:libtensorflow_framework.so.2.10.0: no such attribute 'shared_lib_name' in 'cc_shared_library' rule
ERROR: C:/users/me/documents/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:1034:21: //tensorflow:libtensorflow_framework.so.2.10.0: no such attribute 'win_def_file' in 'cc_shared_library' rule
ERROR: C:/users/me/documents/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:1034:21: //tensorflow:libtensorflow_framework.2.10.0.dylib: no such attribute 'shared_lib_name' in 'cc_shared_library' rule
ERROR: C:/users/me/documents/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:1034:21: //tensorflow:libtensorflow_framework.2.10.0.dylib: no such attribute 'win_def_file' in 'cc_shared_library' rule
ERROR: C:/users/me/documents/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:1034:21: //tensorflow:tensorflow_framework.dll: no such attribute 'shared_lib_name' in 'cc_shared_library' rule
ERROR: C:/users/me/documents/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:1034:21: //tensorflow:tensorflow_framework.dll: no such attribute 'win_def_file' in 'cc_shared_library' rule
ERROR: C:/users/me/documents/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:1156:21: //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so.2.10.0: no such attribute 'shared_lib_name' in 'cc_shared_library' rule
ERROR: C:/users/me/documents/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:1156:21: //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so.2.10.0: no such attribute 'win_def_file' in 'cc_shared_library' rule
ERROR: C:/users/me/documents/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:1156:21: //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.2.10.0.dylib: no such attribute 'shared_lib_name' in 'cc_shared_library' rule
ERROR: C:/users/me/documents/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:1156:21: //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.2.10.0.dylib: no such attribute 'win_def_file' in 'cc_shared_library' rule
ERROR: C:/users/me/documents/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:1156:21: //tensorflow:tensorflow_cc.dll: no such attribute 'shared_lib_name' in 'cc_shared_library' rule
ERROR: C:/users/me/documents/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:1156:21: //tensorflow:tensorflow_cc.dll: no such attribute 'win_def_file' in 'cc_shared_library' rule
ERROR: C:/users/me/documents/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:278:10: errors encountered resolving select() keys for //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted:
INFO: Elapsed time: 155.947s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (9 packages loaded, 12 targets configured)
```

I'm running these commands in a **Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt** in a **Python 3.9.7** virtual environment.  I tried both the `master` branch, shown here, and the `v2.9.1` tag.  They both have the same problems.  I'm posting this problem here as directed on the [TensorFlow Build and install error messages](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors) page.

Comment: Please ask the [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) and bazel teams

Comment: Hi @Chris, as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#install_visual_c_build_tools_2019) that Tensorflow is tested against Visual Studio 2019, please use Visual Studio 2019 and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you!